# Use blank line as file separator in awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I need to know if its possible to use a new line as a field seperator in awk to bring multiple lines in a single line ?

for example:

```
$ cat yo  
a aa aaa  
bb bbb bbb  
cccc ccccc cccc  
ddd dddd ddd  
eeeee eeeee eee  

fffff ffffff fffffff  
gggg ggggg  
hhhhhh hhhhhhh hhhhhhhhh  

iii iiiiiiiii iiiii  
jjjj jjjjj jjjjj  
kkkkk kkkkk  
lllllllll lll ll
```

Below are the few thing my little brain could think of,but none helped.

```
cat file |awk -F'\n' '{print}'    
cat yo |awk 'NF'  '{print $NF}'  


cat yo |awk -F'/^$/d'  '{print $NF}'  
cat yo |awk -F'^$^[ \t]*$' '{print $NF}'  

cat yo |awk -F'^..' '{print $NF}'  

cat yo |awk -F'\t' '{print}'
```

desired output:

```
a aa aaa  bb bbb bbb cccc ccccc cccc ddd dddd ddd eeeee eeeee eee  
fffff ffffff fffffff gggg ggggg hhhhhh hhhhhhh hhhhhhhhh  
iii iiiiiiiii iiiii jjjj jjjjj jjjjj kkkkk kkkkk lllllllll lll ll
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the record separator as `RS=`, which will make it paragraph-wise: every line is a field, every record is a block:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF?"\n":" ")}' file
a aa aaa bb bbb bbb cccc ccccc cccc ddd dddd ddd eeeee eeeee eee 
fffff ffffff fffffff gggg ggggg hhhhhh hhhhhhh hhhhhhhhh 
iii iiiiiiiii iiiii jjjj jjjjj jjjjj kkkkk kkkkk lllllllll lll ll
```

Which is in fact the same as:

```
awk -v RS= '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF?ORS:FS)}' file
```

Comment: Ahem - `awk -v RS= '$1=$1' file`.

Comment: @EdMorton true! I saw your answer few minutes ago and it shines more than mine :) I somehow found it necessary to `print` to have the content reprocessed. Now I see `$1=$1` suffices. Good one!

Comment: The general case or recompiling $0 and printing it is `{$1=$1}1` to account for cases where the record is empty, but that doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: @EdMorton If size matter you can shorten it even some `awk '$1=$1' RS=  file`

Comment: Size generally doesn't matter and as I may have mentioned once or twice setting variables after the script in the list of file names is for changing values between files, otherwise it's clearer and less error prone to set them at the front of the script with `-v`.

Answer (score 3):

**THE** way to do this in awk is simply:

```
$ awk -v RS= '$1=$1' file
a aa aaa bb bbb bbb cccc ccccc cccc ddd dddd ddd eeeee eeeee eee
fffff ffffff fffffff gggg ggggg hhhhhh hhhhhhh hhhhhhhhh
iii iiiiiiiii iiiii jjjj jjjjj jjjjj kkkkk kkkkk lllllllll lll ll
```

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want to redefine the record delimiter instead of the field delimiter....

Quoting `man awk`

```
Records
   Normally, records are separated by newline characters.  You can control 
   how records are separated by assigning values to the built-in variable
   RS.  If RS is any single character, that character separates records.  
   Otherwise, RS is a regular expression.  Text in the input that  matches
   this  regular expression separates the record.  However, in compatibility 
   mode, only the first character of its string value is used for separating 
   records.  If RS is set to the null string, then records are separated by 
   blank lines.  When RS is set to the null string,  the  newline character 
   always acts as a field separator, in addition to whatever value FS may have.
```

So try this;

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n";}{print NF;}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use any constraint to use `awk`, it can done simply using a loop, reading line by line:

```
while read -r line ; do 
  if [[ -z $line ]]; then echo ;  else echo -n $line;  fi 
done <file
```

Comment: Would this not concatenate lines without spaces in beetween? And it would be better to avoid extra space in the end of the output line. Edit: I didn't see that input lines end with spaces sorry.

Comment: Good one! Also `[[ -z "$line" ]] && echo || echo -n "$line "` would make it.

Answer (score 1):

Through `awk's` gsub function,

```
$ awk -v RS="" '{gsub(/\n/,"")}1' file
a aa aaa  bb bbb bbb  cccc ccccc cccc  ddd dddd ddd  eeeee eeeee eee  
fffff ffffff fffffff  gggg ggggg  hhhhhh hhhhhhh hhhhhhhhh  
iii iiiiiiiii iiiii  jjjj jjjjj jjjjj  kkkkk kkkkk  lllllllll lll ll
```